# I cannot include an icon when I compile my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I am using `pyinstaller` to compile my programs. I cannot include files with the `-i` option. It doesn't compile and instead gives an error. The whole compiler crashes. My error code is here: https://pastebin.com/raw/UBTTMmke I was using powershell after I shift+right-clicked the directory in explorer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error message instead of linking to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you 'cd' first on your script's folder destination.
2. Make sure your image file is converted as .ico file and also in your script's folder

Then try compiling your script as:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon Your_logo.ico My_script.py
```

Also if you want your console not to pop up when the script is running you can use the 'windowed' option:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon Your_logo.ico My_script.py
```

Comment: actually, I found an answer to this question just this morning before I checked stack overflow. Same thing, but the no console is --noconsole parameter. Also, I need to write --icon="icon_filename.ico" instead of iicon Icon_filename.ico. By this morning I mean 4-19-2019

Comment: As of python 3.7.1, --icon and the -i option no longer work.